# GroupBy functionality with RowHideShow in NatTable

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I'm trying to include Row hide/show in NatTable with group by funtionality.
By using org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.hideshow.RowIdHideShowLayer the group by functionality itself doesn't work.
So I tried with:
public org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists.hideshow.GlazedListsRowHideShowLayer(ILayer underlyingLayer, IRowDataProvider rowDataProvider, IRowIdAccessor rowIdAccessor)
The group by is working but the row hide/show doesn't happen.

Can I get an idea on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. As you don't provide more detailed information, I can't tell you any details about a possible solution. But you can have a look at one of our integration examples (Tutorial Examples - Integration - EditableSortableGroupByWithFilterExample). This shows exactly the requested feature set.